# offline installation of swa cli will work?

Tags: npm, azure-devops, jfrog-cli, azure-static-web-app

we dont have direct connectivity to nodejs.org site from our Build agent linux machine and only Jfrog proxy repo for npm packages we are using.

We configured the jfrog settings on the repo to connect our build machine. But the  "npm install -g @azure/static-web-apps-cli" is not working.

Is there any offline installation method for swacli ?

Our requirement is to run Azuredevops server pipeline to deploy the webapps. But we couldn't find the staticwebapp task in azuredevops server and also the swa cli offline installation of getting failed is failing.

Comment: Maybe I would like to know why you want to go with this route.... When you say it doesn't work, what do you mean? Does the installation fail? If installation fails can you share the logs or tell us why it fails?